# Building with CruiseControl.Net uses wrong outputdir

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, cruisecontrol.net

I have a project that changed the output directory to bin\Debug.  It builds fine on my dev machine and the output directory is correct...bin\Debug.

On our build server we are running CruiseControl.net.  The build fails and looking at the logs, its building to the wrong output path.  Example : "C:\Program Files (x86)\Test1\Test1\".  This is not the previous output path either.  Looking at the csproj file for that project, I don't see that path in there.  Its not the working directory for the CruiseControl project.

I believe this has something to do with CruiseControl.Net because if I use devenv to build the project on the build server from commandline, it has the correct output path.

This is also not happening with all my CruiseControl projects.

Any ideas where this path is cached in CC?

Comment: I've never used CC, however in other CI environments I've used, there are multiple directory variables that can be used when setting up build commands.  Be sure that you aren't using relative paths that may be pointing to the installation directory or something like that instead of the intended build directory.

Comment: I have checked all paths that I am aware of in CruiseControl.Net (.state files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using devenv to build the project through CruiseControl.Net.  I switched to the MSBuild task and specify my OutputPath in the buildArgs and it works as I expect.  This wasn't the solution I was looking for but it will do.

```
         <msbuild>
            <executable>$(v4_MSBuild)</executable>
            <workingDirectory>$(SourceRoot)$(TrunkDir)project1</workingDirectory>
            <projectFile>$(SourceRoot)$(TrunkDir)project1\main.sln</projectFile>
            <buildArgs>/p:Configuration=Debug;OutputPath="bin\Debug" /v:n</buildArgs>
            <targets>Build</targets>
            <timeout>900</timeout>
            <logger>C:\Program Files (x86)\CruiseControl.NET\server\ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MsBuild.dll</logger>
        </msbuild>
```

Comment: using msbuild.exe (or an msbuild task) is a better solution IMHO.  I don't like installing the IDE (devenv.exe) on the build machine.  It installs too many hidden dependencies IMHO.